# How is a raw string useful in Python?

Tags: python

I know the raw string operator `r` or `R` suppresses the meaning of escape characters but in what situation would this really be helpful?

Comment: File paths: `r'C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\file.txt'`.

Comment: And Regular expression `r'\d+'`

Comment: why would you use this anyways? If you take it out it does not affect how the code is displayed because I tried running the string without the r character and everything ran as expected with no errors or anything

Comment: @thuang Try a path like `C:\tools\new-stuff\blue\red.txt`.

Comment: @thuang:  also common in regular expressions are `"\1\2\3"`: try that with and without the `r`.

Answer (score 8):

Raw strings are commonly used for regular expressions which need to include backslashes.

```
re.match(r'\b(\w)+', string)  # instead of re.match('(\\w)+', string
```

They are also useful for DOS file paths, which would otherwise have to double up every path separator.

```
path = r'C:\some\dir'  # instead of 'C:\\some\\dir'
```

Comment: Note that you only need to use raw strings in regular expressions for the `\b` escape sequence.

Comment: Some, but not all, functions accept `/` as a universal path separator, converting it to a backslash if necessary.

Comment: I'm not so sure Python does anything.  `/` and `\\` are valid directory separators on Windows at the API level.   *File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the "\\?\" prefix* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So basically it is just a way of structuring your code depending on whether or not you want to use it? Sorry for all these stupid questions. I know \n creates a newline and \t creates a horizontal tab, but what does the escape sequence \b do?

Comment: @thuang In a regular expression it’s a word boundary; in a normal string it’s the bell character though which is why you need to escape it if you want the word boundary.

Answer (score 6):

They save you from the [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

> the situation in which a quoted expression becomes unreadable because it contains a large number of escape characters, usually backslashes ("\")

Answer (score 0):

Raw strings are helpful as they save you from adding escape characters just to escape 'escape characters'. For example `r'url\1'` is equivalent to `'url\\1'`